# Prevent Spawning Prefabs At The Same Position In A Row

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, spawn

i am trying to develop a unity game which uses prefabs spawn at random locations from an array. The problem i am having is prefabs are spawning on the top of each other too many times. I have tried to prevent this from happening with the help of other topics not only here but also from google but i couldnt apply some methods to my code. So my goal is keep tracking last spawned object position and spawn next object at diffrent position from the array i have created within the obstacle script. Is there anyone who can help me?

This is my obstacle scripts which attached to prefabs.

```
public class obstacle : MonoBehaviour

{
    private Rigidbody targetRb;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private float minSpeed = 12;
    private float maxSpeed = 16;
    private float ySpawnPos = 6;
    private float NewPosition = -1.87f;
    private List<Vector3> spawnPositions = new List<Vector3>();
    private int index;
    public int offset = 1;
    


    void Start()
    {
      
        index = Random.Range(0, spawns.Length);
       
        transform.position = spawns[index];
        
        
       

    }

   

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    Vector3 RandomForce()
    {
        return Vector3.down * Random.Range(minSpeed, maxSpeed);
    }

     Vector3[] spawns = new[]
    //spawns = new Vector3[]
    { 
        new Vector3(-2.16f,7,0), 
        new Vector3(-0.67f,7,0), 
        new Vector3(0.75f,7,0), 
        new Vector3(2.22f,7,0) 
    };
}
```

This is my game manager script which spawn the prefabs.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour

//spawnera alternatif daha güzel
{
    public List<GameObject> targets;
   
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    public int score;
    public TextMeshProUGUI scoreText;
    public TextMeshProUGUI gameOverText;
    public Button restartButton;
    public bool isGameActive;
    public float spawnRate = 3.0f;
    public Text highScore;
    public Text highestScore;
    
    

   

    void Start()
    {
        isGameActive = true;
        score = 0;
        UpdateScore(0);
        StartCoroutine(SpawnTarget());
        highScore.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore", 0).ToString();
       
        

    }
    IEnumerator  SpawnTarget()
    {
        while (isGameActive)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnRate);
            int index = Random.Range(0, targets.Count);
            Instantiate(targets[index]);


            UpdateScore(5); 

            if(score > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore",0))
            {
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore", score);
                highScore.text = score.ToString();
            }
            
           
        }
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    public void UpdateScore(int scoreToAdd)
    {

        score += scoreToAdd;
        scoreText.text = "Score: " + score;

    }

    public void GameOver()
    {
        restartButton.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        gameOverText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        isGameActive = false;
        Time.timeScale = 0;
        highScore.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        highestScore.gameObject.SetActive(true);


    }
    public void RestartGame()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
        Time.timeScale = 1;
        
        
    }
     
  }
```

Comment: Try using a [SphereCast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html). Before spawning at a location, use a sphere cast of the largest dimension of your object (width, height or length) and set this value to the radius of the sphere cast. If the cast detects another object, either try to adjust so the cast is no longer touching or randomly generate a new point until it finds a valid location.

Comment: Hello, fisrtly thank you for the answer. I habe tried to do it but couldnt implement it to my code and it doesnt work( ı couldt make it work). But i will try again.

Comment: I just re-read your question. Are you trying to spawn prefabs randomly from a pre-defined list of positions, and want the spawns to be more spread equally? Or do you want fully random spawn locations of given some [min, max) of each axis?

Comment: I am trying to spawn prefabs randomly from a pre defined list of positions and spawns to be more spread equally yes. So that the prefabs shouldnt be spawned at the same position twice in a row.

Comment: If you want to fully equally spread out each time, I would randomize your list, then add them to a queue or stack, then pop it each time you need a position. When the queue/stack reaches a size of 0, randomize the list again and fill it again. If you do this, it would be spread out evenly each time exactly. If this is what you want I can type up an example.

Comment: If you can, that would be great! Btw, it doesnt habe to be fully equally spread out but with current code, they are spawend at the same position like 3-4 times in a row and they are overlapping. I want to avoid that but if it is easier, fully equally spread out work too. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A stack or queue might be a bit overkill, so instead, I'll just keep an iterator and check if we are exceeding the bounds of your array. I am also going to move the initial placement to the GameManager so it can manage which positions are left in the spawn list locations.

```
    // move the array of locations to the GameManager
    Vector3[] spawns = new[]
    { 
        new Vector3(-2.16f,7,0), 
        new Vector3(-0.67f,7,0), 
        new Vector3(0.75f,7,0), 
        new Vector3(2.22f,7,0) 
    };
    
    private int currentSpawnItr = 0;
    private int maxSpawnItr = 0;

    private System.Random rndm;

    private void Start()
    {
         rndm = new System.Random();
         maxSpawnItr = spawns.Length;
         ShufflePositions();
    }

    IEnumerator  SpawnTarget()
    {
        while (isGameActive)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnRate);
            int index = Random.Range(0, targets.Count);
            GameObject tmpObstacle = Instantiate(targets[index]);

            tmpObstacle.transform.position = GetNextPosition();

            UpdateScore(5); 

            if(score > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore",0))
            {
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore", score);
                highScore.text = score.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    private Vector3 GetNextPosition()
    {
         // when we reach the bounds of our spawn array length, shuffle it again
         // and reset our iterator
         if(currentSpawnItr == maxSpawnItr)
         {
             currentSpawnItr = 0;
             ShufflePositions();
         }

         ++currentSpawnItr;
         return spawns[currentSpawnItr-1];
    }

    private void ShufflePositions()
    {
         Vector3 prevLast = spawns[maxSpawnItr-1];
         spawns = spawns.OrderBy(spawn => rndm.Next()).ToArray();
         
         // when our new first spawn was our old last spawn
         if(spawns[0] == prevLast)
         {
              // randomly pick an index to swap our first element to
              int randomIdx = rndm.Next(1, maxSpawnItr);
              spawns[0] = spawns[randomIdx];
              spawns[randomIdx] = prevLast;
         }
    }
```

I have not tested the above snippet. It is more the direction you could take this. If you have issues implementing this let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have implemented that into the project and it is working almost perfectly! The usage of same position in a row is almost zero but unfortunately, it is still happening at some intervals(way much rarely ofcourse, again thank you!). I have tried change this line of your code "maxSpawnItr = spawns.Length"  with "maxSpawnItr = spawns.Length-1;" but couldnt prevent it from happening.

Comment: It should not exceed a stack larger than 2 greater than any other. The only time this would happen is if the previous randomly generated array has a position that occurs as the first item of the new array. If you never want this occurring you can duplicate the previous array and if the previous array's last element is the first, then swap the first and last elements in the new array.

Comment: @CemalKarakuş I edited the answer. If what I think is occurring is happening, the new code should make it so the first element of the new generated array is never the same as the last array's last element. I am doing a rather trivial swap, if you want it to be more random, you can pick a random index to swap with instead of the last element.

Comment: I updated the snippet again. The swapped element now chooses a random element from index 1 to the end of the array to swap with instead of just swapping the end element.

Comment: Thats awesome, thank you very much for all of your effort and help!

Comment: @CemalKarakuş Anytime. Whenever you feel this answer is fully answered you can click the green checkmark and/or the upvote button. If you have more follow-up questions about this question just ask away.

Comment: I did. Acctually there is one more thing, when game is restarted or started for the first time, the spawns are always from first vector to the last vector rather then randomly picked vectors. If we can figure that out too, that would be perfect but if we cant, thats still perfect!

Comment: @CemalKarakuş Updated the answer. I believe if you just add a `ShufflePositions()` call to the `Start()` function it should shuffle the positions on the first loop through. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: @CemalKarakuş For sure. Good luck with your project!